# ModelChoiceField: how to show attributes and not objects?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have two tables (`Subject` and `Languae`) with only one attribute, `subject` and `language`, each. In the relative form's fields I want to see a dropdown menu with the value of the attribute but with this code:

```
lang = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Language.objects.order_by('?'), required=False, label='What language want to search?')
subject = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Subject.objects.order_by('?'), required=False, label='Whitch subject you want to search?')
```

I see the dropdown menu filled of `Subject object` and `Language object` which are identical from one onother.

How can i show the actual value of the object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution is to implement your `Language` and `Subject` models `__unicode__` method to make it return the attribute you want to display (or any unicode string built upon any combination of attributes or whatever). In your case:

```
 class Subject(models.Model):
     subject = models.CharField(....)

     def __unicode__(self):
         return self.subject
```

and ditto for Language

For more advanced usage, this is documented here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield

Note that you don't really have to create a `ModelChoiceField` subclass to override `label_from_instance` - you can also just monkeypatch the `ModelChoiceField` *instance* with a `lambda` in your form's `__init__`